# XML response POST request with CURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, soap

I have to invoke a soap web service using curl and php.
I tried this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd................</soapenv:Envelope>");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This code works well but I can't to print the result as XML.

If I use other client to invoke the same service I obtain a XML response (this is correct). Why?

Comment: SOAP services are best consumed with ... *drum rolls* ... [SoapClient](http://php.net/soapclient)!

Comment: @Ja͢ck I think he already did that.

Comment: @Daan Really? From which part of the question does that become obvious?

Comment: 'If I use other client' could have more meanings though. I didn't say it's obvious

Comment: I not use SoapClient

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? and what's the content of the $result variable?